# Reactive Spring Security PostAuthorize annotation doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, reactive

Using Webflux and Reactive Spring Security, how do you do post processing via annotations to control access to methods?

Trying a very basic sample, I'm not able to get the value from the `PostAuthorize` annotation. For example

```
  @GetMapping
  @PostAuthorize("#email == authentication.principal.email")
  public Flux<Project> sampleTest(final String email) {
    log.info("email: {}", email);

    return Flux.empty();
  }
```

The email will always be null. I have the basic wiring working to the fact if I set something like `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")` I'll get back a 403.

I can extract the Authentication out with a helper like:

```
  public Mono<Authentication> getAuthentication() {
    return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
        .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
        .flatMap(Mono::just);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not be understanding your question correctly, but the `PostAuthorize` uses the return object - the body of the method doesn't have access to anything in the SPEL expression.

Something like this might work -

```
@GetMapping
  @PostAuthorize("returnObject == someCondition")
  public Flux<Project> sampleTest(final String email) {
    // get some data and return it
  }
```

But maybe you want to filter the items in the Flux?
You might look at the `@PostFilter` annotation -

```
// assuming there's an email property on your Project object.
@GetMapping
  @PostFilter("filterObject.getEmail() == authentication.principal.email")
  public Flux<Project> sampleTest() {
    // get some data and return it
  }
```